# Fluent nhibernate configuration - UseOuterJoin(), ProxyFactoryFactory()

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've seen the following line of code:

```
return MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .UseOuterJoin()
                .ProxyFactoryFactory(typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory))
                .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ApplicationServices"))
                .ShowSql();
```

Looking in fluent's [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Database-configuration) I got the explanation about "self explanation".
I would appreciate if somebody explain the meaning of UseOuterJoin(), ProxyFactoryFactory() or give a link to read myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-outerjoin

> If your database supports ANSI or Oracle style outer joins, outer join
>   fetching might increase performance by limiting the number of round
>   trips to and from the database (at the cost of possibly more work
>   performed by the database itself). Outer join fetching allows a graph
>   of objects connected by many-to-one, one-to-many or one-to-one
>   associations to be retrieved in a single SQL SELECT.
>
> By default, the fetched graph when loading an objects ends at leaf
>   objects, collections, objects with proxies, or where circularities
>   occur.
>
> For a particular association, fetching may be configured (and the
>   default behaviour overridden) by setting the fetch attribute in the
>   XML mapping.

http://nhibernate.info/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx

ProxyFactoryFactory just specifies how your proxies will be created.